# Drop Down List Values Not Being Sent To Database

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a page where values from a table in my database are being pulled out and shown on a drop down list. Once a value is chosen and the form is submitted, every data apart from the drop down list is submitted to my mysql database. the code is as follows:

```
   <?
$sql="SELECT user_id, firstname FROM Users WHERE role = 'chairperson'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$options="";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $id=$row["user_id"];
    $thing=$row["firstname"];
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$thing; 
}
?>
<form action="meetingsinserted.php" method="post">
...
<tr>
    <td>      <label for="chairperson">Chairperson:</label>
</td>
    <td><span id="spryselect1">
      <select name="thing" id="chairperson">

<OPTION VALUE=0>
<?=$options?>

     </select>
      <span class="selectRequiredMsg">You Must Choose A Chairperson For This Meeting</span></span></td>
  </tr>
...
```

meetingsinserted.php page is as follows:

```
     <?php

$title = $_REQUEST['title'];
$chairperson = $_REQUEST['chairperson'];
$secretary = $_REQUEST['secretary'];
$tof = $_REQUEST['tof'];
$occurances = $_REQUEST['occurances'];

$con = mysql_connect("*********","***","****");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('mdb_hj942', $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO Meetings (title, chairperson, secretary, tof, occurances) VALUES ('$title','$chairperson', '$secretary','$tof','$occurances')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
      echo '<h1>Meeting Has Been Sent To Chairperson For Approval</h1>';
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
?>
```

any ideas guys? thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="thing" id="chairperson">
```

It should be

```
<select name="chairperson" id="chairperson">
```

Also, consider adding closing tag for

```
<option>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. it works now, just 1 last question....how comes once my form is submitted, it brings up the word 'error' instead of confirming its submission to the database? it shouldnt be doing that becuase the data is being submitted successfuly. the code i am talking about is.....if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
      echo '<h1>Meeting Has Been Sent To Chairperson For Approval</h1>';
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

Comment: $_REQUEST['chairperson']; is never set and you were trying to access it, so you were seeing that error. Now since you had declared the variable $chairperson, and it was set to null, it created the entry in the database. Also, the column chairperson is not set to NOT NULL so it added the entry successfully.

Comment: Sorry, I got your question wrong...you do not need to change anything...
Just curious why are you doing this? if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
      echo '<h1>Meeting Has Been Sent To Chairperson For Approval</h1>';
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

Comment: Use this--

if (mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
      echo '<h1>Meeting Has Been Sent To Chairperson For Approval</h1>';
  }else{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

Answer (score 0):

First of all close the  tag to have a valid HTML

```
  <?
$sql="SELECT user_id, firstname FROM Users WHERE role = 'chairperson'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$options="";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $id=$row["user_id"];
    $thing=$row["firstname"];
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$thing."</option>"; 
}
?>
<form action="meetingsinserted.php" method="post">
...
<tr>
    <td>      <label for="chairperson">Chairperson:</label>
</td>
    <td><span id="spryselect1">
      <select name="thing" id="chairperson">

<OPTION VALUE=0>
<?=$options?>

     </select>
      <span class="selectRequiredMsg">You Must Choose A Chairperson For This Meeting</span></span></td>
  </tr>
```

And you are trying to get the value by id value attribute and this is not correct you need to call it from the name attribute value

```
 <?php

$title = $_REQUEST['title'];
$chairperson = $_REQUEST['thing']; //here was your problem 
$secretary = $_REQUEST['secretary'];
$tof = $_REQUEST['tof'];
$occurances = $_REQUEST['occurances'];

$con = mysql_connect("*********","***","****");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('mdb_hj942', $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO Meetings (title, chairperson, secretary, tof, occurances) VALUES ('$title','$chairperson', '$secretary','$tof','$occurances')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
      echo '<h1>Meeting Has Been Sent To Chairperson For Approval</h1>';
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
?>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. it works now, just 1 last question....how comes once my form is submitted, it brings up the word 'error' instead of confirming its submission to the database? it shouldnt be doing that becuase the data is being submitted successfuly. the code i am talking about is.....if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
      echo '<h1>Meeting Has Been Sent To Chairperson For Approval</h1>';
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }